# What is the Lewis dot structure for ozone?

Tags: molecular-structure, lewis-structure

Currently I studying about the Lewis dot structure for different compounds and my textbook says that the Lewis structure for ozone may be drawn as(as shown in the image):
[image: Lewis dot structure of Ozone(with formal charge)]
And then it goes on to calculate the formal charges on different oxygen atoms in it(which are shown in figure with $+/-$ signs.) In justification of the structure it says:

> Formal charges help in the selection of the lowest energy structure from a number of possible Lewis structures for a given species. Generally the lowest energy structure is the one with the smallest formal charges on the atoms. The formal charge is a factor based on a pure covalent view of bonding in which electron pairs are shared equally by neighbouring atoms.

Now, my question is why can't the structure  be like this:
[image: My suggested Lewis structure for ozone]

Clearly, if this isn't a possible structure then the flaw in my understanding arises because of not understanding the term 'smallest formal charge'(as I found out that the structure I gave has all oxygen atoms with zero formal charge )
Please suggest what does it mean by the smallest formal charge ? Also why energetically the structure isn't stable. 
(For now please exclude any discussion about resonance hybrid of the ozone)

Comment: The reason the cyclic structure doesn't exist is due to the bond angles. The 60 degree bond angles puts the electrons in the covalent bonds too close to each other. The electron-electron repulsion makes the structure unstable.
Rarely will you find bond angles less than 90 degrees, making cyclic structures with less than 5 in a ring uncommon.

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer.

Comment: I can't post as an answer, it's on hold.